# How to grab a fading effect when JavaScript update the src?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys I have the following code where I update the src for 2 divs. the fading is fine when the images are already loaded but when it update the src there is no fade it jumps from one frame to another.

http://jsfiddle.net/b52to421/

```
var firstFrame, secondFrame, i = 1, x = 4;
div = document.getElementById('frames');
firstFrame = new Image();
secondFrame = new Image();
div.appendChild(firstFrame);
div.appendChild(secondFrame);
firstFrame.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
secondFrame.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + x + '.jpg';
firstFrame.id = "top";
secondFrame.id = "back";

startAd = function() {
    container = document.getElementById("top");
    windowH = container.height;
    windowW = container.width;
    console.log(windowW + " x " + windowH);
    //
    frame = document.getElementById("frames");
    frame.style.height = windowH + "px";
    frame.style.width = windowW + "px";
    firstFrame();
}

firstFrame = function(){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        if(i > 4) {
            i=1;
        } 
        var element = document.getElementById("top");
        element.outerHTML = "";
        delete element;
        //
        if(i > 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            firstFrame = new Image();
            div.appendChild(firstFrame);
            firstFrame.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
            firstFrame.id = "top";
        }
    }, 8000, secondFrame());
}

secondFrame = function(){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        x++;
        if(x > 4) {
            x=1;
        } 
        var element = document.getElementById("back");
        element.outerHTML = "";
        delete element;
        //
        if(x > 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            secondFrame = new Image();
            div.appendChild(secondFrame);
            secondFrame.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + x + '.jpg';
            secondFrame.id = "back";
        }
    }, 8000);
}
```